# What happens to unique buildings in occupied cities?

Tags: civilization-5

How does capturing cities handle unique buildings?

For example: If China conquers a city with a library, does the library transform into a paper maker?

or like wise if I conquer a Chinese city as another civilization does the paper maker turn back into a library?

The possibilities I can think of are:

- The unique/non-unique building remains (In which case you can sell it and rebuild it as your civ's version)
- The building will transform back and forward depending on the owner
- Buildings will be deleted on transfer of owner.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Paper Maker and the Wat are transformed into a Library and a University. The other unique buildings I tried were destroyed.

I'm pretty certain that some classes of buildings are always destroyed, but there is probably also a random factor.

The XML files have some information about it, the probability of capture for the unique buildings is the following

```
Longhouse          66%
Bazaar             75%
Satraps Court      75%
Paper Maker        66%
Wat                66%
```

For the other unique buildings there is no value given, I assume that they are always destroyed.

Comment: That answers half of it, I'm curious the other half though (if you capture a city with a library and are Chinese - does it turn into a paper maker?).

Comment: @Daniel Lew: I would assume it is symmetrical.